# Generate HTML DOM from nested object

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a nested object like it for example :

```
let obj = {
  first: {
    entry: {
      really: {
        nested: 'true'
      }
    },
    entryOther: 'here'
  },
  simple: 'it'
}
```

I try to convert this structure into HTML dom element with nested nodes.

I try this :

```
let domFromObj;
const constructDOMFromObj = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach( key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      domFromObj += '<div>';
      domFromObj += `<input id="${key}" class="block nested" type="text" value="${key}" />`;
      constructDOMFromObj(obj[key]);
    } else {
      domFromObj += '<div>';
      domFromObj += `<input class="" type="text" value="${key}" />`;
      domFromObj += '</div>';
      domFromObj += '<div>';
      domFromObj += `<input class="" type="text" value="${obj[key]}" />`;
      domFromObj += '</div>';
    }

  })
  return domFromObj;
}

const init = () => {
  $('body').append('<pre></pre>');
  let codeElement = $('body pre');
  let DomObj = constructDOMFromObj(obj);
  codeElement.append(DomObj);
  DomObj = new DOMParser().parseFromString(DomObj, "text/xml");
}

init();
```

But my structure is not correct, i don't arrive to close divs when nested object finished, i can't detect when nested is finished to close div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the recursive approach,
After constructDOMFromObj(obj[key]);  add
      domFromObj += ''
Try using :

```
let domFromObj;
const constructDOMFromObj = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach( key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      domFromObj += '<div>';
      domFromObj += `<input id="${key}" class="block nested" type="text" 
      value="${key}" />`;
      constructDOMFromObj(obj[key]);
      domFromObj += '</div>'
    } else {
      domFromObj += '<div>';
      domFromObj += `<input class="" type="text" value="${key}" />`;
      domFromObj += '</div>';
      domFromObj += '<div>';
      domFromObj += `<input class="" type="text" value="${obj[key]}" />`;
      domFromObj += '</div>';
    }

  })
  return domFromObj;
}

const init = () => {
  $('body').append('<pre></pre>');
  let codeElement = $('body pre');
  let DomObj = constructDOMFromObj(obj);
  codeElement.append(DomObj);
  DomObj = new DOMParser().parseFromString(DomObj, "text/xml");
}

init();
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if I'm getting you correctly but, from the if condition.... you didn't add a closing  after the input tag